# Popular "random" strings

Tags: kana

Some "random" letter/numbers strings, like `bxdrpcqazwsui1`, gives a whole bunch of Japanese results if typed on Bing search engine.
I don't know why these strings are related to Japanese, and none of the search results actually shows the strings.

Please explain why those Japanese results appear.

Comment: I think it's probably a quirk of the engine more than anything

Comment: People actually use Bing?

Comment: @istrasci Sorry, I can't access Google.

Answer (score 6):

Where did you see `bxdrpcqazwsui1`? It is not a truly random string. It's what you get when you try to input こさしすせそたちつてとなにぬ (a part of [Japanese alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana)) using a [Japanese keyboard](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Japanese.svg) with the English mode accidentally turned on.

The full version (from あ to ん) would be `3E456TGH:BXDRPCQAZWSUI1,KFV2^-JN]/M789OL.;_0Y`.